# Facebook Graph API gets Square picture of wall post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900780/graph-api-get-photo-square-100x100), I know that we can obtain user profile picture in square shape by appending `?type=square` in Graph API URL , such as :

> https://graph.facebook.com/{FACEBOOK_USER_ID}/picture?type=square

But how about the images in wall post ? I know that I can obtain the picture URLs ( of different dimensions ) by this Graph API call :

> https://graph.facebook.com/{OBJECT_ID}/

However, the type parameter does not support `square`. It supports `thumbail`, `normal` and `album` only. But none of them returns the square image shown in timeline . ( I also need the reposition information, as I used the "Reposition Photo" in Timeline ). Does Graph API provide such information ?

*Note: I use PHP , but I think the programming language is independent*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Graph API does not provide the data on how the photo is repositioned on a Timeline or Newsfeed.

In the context of the API, "Square" does not refer to any photo size of equal dimensions. But rather it refers to the image used as the user's avatar next to posts. So given this logic, regular photo objects would not include a "square" implementation because that photo will never be used as an avatar. If you want an image of equal dimensions on each side, you'll have to implement that yourself.

Comment: thanks for the information. it would be grateful if there is official documentation provided. ( I can't find it in the Facebook Developer documentation )