# Facebook Graph API exact dimensions of custom picture sizes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901236/3927799) old post by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) and was wondering if anyone had figured something out yet. I quote:

> https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?width=150&height=150 – asking for 150x150, getting 156x156 instead.

Does anyone know exactly how Facebook rounds the custom values? Why does 150x150 return 156x156 when the standard sizes are 50x50 and 100x100?

Comment: As far as I know there are fixed sizes and they will return the size as close to your requested size as possible.

Comment: But does Facebook offer any universal sizes?