# High Resolution Images from facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is how I am getting photo albums and pictures from the album.

```
let connectionPhotos = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
let requestPhotos = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: String(format:"/%@/photos",albumID), parameters: ["fields":"picture.type(large)"], HTTPMethod: "GET")
connectionPhotos.addRequest(requestPhotos) { (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if(error != nil){
        print(error)
        self.btnFacebook.userInteractionEnabled = true
        connectionPhotos.cancel()
    }else{
        connectionPhotos.cancel()
        self.arrImages = result["data"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, String>>

        if let userWSRequestKey = TRUserModel.SharedInstance()?.userWSRequestKey{
            if userWSRequestKey != X_API_DEFAULT_KEY{
                self.callSignInWS(dict)
            } else{
                JSONParser.sharedInstance.parseRequestKeyWithURL("", requestPrm: ["string":"string"], completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
                    if response["status"] as! Int == 1 {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                            self.callSignInWS(dict)
                        })
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                            self.showAlertView(INTERNET_PROBLEM)
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        } else{
            JSONParser.sharedInstance.parseRequestKeyWithURL("", requestPrm: ["string":"string"], completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
                if response["status"] as! Int == 1 {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                        self.callSignInWS(dict)
                    })
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                        self.showAlertView(INTERNET_PROBLEM)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
connectionPhotos.start()
```

- Simply I have 414*414 pixel size image and I am getting images through above code are small So it's going to blur in my application. So, how can I get large images.
- Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with this graph path

```
GET /v2.6/{photo-id}/?fields=images
```

i'm getting an array of images of different sizes.

example:

`{
      "height": 1365,
      "source": "...",
      "width": 2048
    },
    {
      "height": 960,
      "source": "...",
      "width": 1440
    },
    {
      "height": 720,
      "source": "...",
      "width": 1080
    }`

hope this helped :D