# Facebook Graph API Pages Albums - Specifying size for the images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am fetching albums from a Facebook page using the Graph API (v3). 
I then process each album individually and request its photos, reaching at the **album edge**.

```
/{album-id}?fields=photos{id,images}
```

Ideally, I would like to find a way to specify a desired size/type (for example thumbnail or width = 640px) for the photos.

Is there any way?

---

*This question is about the album edge. Answers on questions like:
[Facebook Graph API : get larger pictures in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650730/facebook-graph-api-get-larger-pictures-in-one-request), or [Graph API get photo square (100x100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900780/graph-api-get-photo-square-100x100/11901236) are not a solution to this question.

Comment: in addition to the duplicate thread that should answer your question already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900780/graph-api-get-photo-square-100x100/11901236

Comment: @luschn - thanks for the links, but I have read them. None of the answers works for me and the Graph API v3 for the album edge.

Comment: you did not include what you have tried so far, so it was a clear duplicate for me, sorry. you should add your research and testing code.

Comment: Hey @luschn, I had tried a ton of things working on this specific project for days. I thought that specifying the album edge and posting my main graph request would be sufficient, as this is the case that I am looking for some help. If there is any special syntax that would allow me to specify the desired size for the album images. If there is any I can't find it, whatever I have tried in the graph explorer. Do you know if this is at all possible somehow?